# Copy files skipping duplicates VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, copy, copy-paste, skip

I am copying some folders with:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(folder, destination)
```

And they obviously do have content. So I want to skip the duplicate files, how do I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the [parameter overwrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127958.aspx) to false

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(folder, destination, false)
```

This will raise an exception when, in the destination folder, a file to be copied exist, but the missing files in the destination are still copied.

See the documentation on [CopyDirectory(source, dest, overwrite)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127958.aspx) to know how to handle the exception

Comment: Thanks! Silly that i didn't look there! haha